# How can I make a new column by adding two columns with a priority given to one of them?

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe and I want to get C as shown. Checking if there is a value for A then it would appear in C. If there is no value in A, then C will take B value.

```
data <- 
structure(list(A = c(15L, 20L, NA, 8L), B = c(7L, NA, 9L, 6L), 
    C = c(15L, 20L, 9L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

I tried something like:

```
data$C <- coalesce(data$A, data$B)
```

Comment: Looks like the code you show does give the output you show. What is the issue?

Comment: Like Toucan said  your code is good. What are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
data %>% mutate(C = coalesce(A, B))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution using `ifelse`

```
data$C <- with(data,ifelse(is.na(A),B,A))
```

or `which` + `aggregate`

```
data$C <- data[as.matrix(aggregate(col~row,which(!is.na(data),arr.ind = TRUE),FUN = min))]
```